# How can I implement a chain method for my class?

Tags: arrays, ruby, type-conversion

I'm working with a string that has to be converted to a 2 dimensional array:

```
rows = [['1', '2'], ['10', '20']]
```

I need those values as integers instead of strings. I can iterate through them and then do `map`, like:

```
rows.each {|row| row.map!(&:to_i)}
```

I was trying to create a `to_i` method that could be chainable, so I can run `rows.to_i`.

```
def to_i
  each do |nested|
    nested.map!(&:to_i)
  end
end
```

This unsurprisingly fails:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `to_i' for [["1", "2"], ["10", "20"]]:Array
```

since `Array` doesn't implement the method. Besides monkey patching the `Array` class, is there a proper or more rubier way to do it?

The other alternative is doing:

```
def ary_to_i array
  array.each do |nested|
    nested.map!(&:to_i)
  end
end
```

but I found the method call `ary_to_i(rows)` confusing.

Comment: Wouldn't it be possible to do the string->int casting somewhere before, where it's easier? We don't see the whole method, so it's just a guess, but it's something I'd look for.

Comment: I would say the Ruby way is to abandon your quest. Even if you were agreeable to adding a method `to_i` to `Array` it would only apply to elements of arrays that are strings, which would be ugly beyond words.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could define a `to_i` method just for rows:

```
rows = [['1','2'], ['10','20']]

def rows.to_i
  each do |nested|
    nested.map!(&:to_i)
  end
end

p rows.to_i # => [[1, 2], [10, 20]]
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it’s an anti-pattern, you might monkey-patch the `Array` class:

```
class Array
  def to_i
    map do |nested|
      nested.map(&:to_i)
    end
  end
  def to_i!
    each do |nested|
      nested.map!(&:to_i)
    end
  end
end
```

But I’d better go with the latter alternative in OP.

---

*Sidenote:* mutating arrays is not a best idea ever, but if you do, choose the name ending with a bang as in my example.